# react web created by CRA(create-react-app) always redirect to '/'

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I made a default react web with CRA and start it.

And type arbitrary path in address bar like this.

http://localhost:3000/whatever/path

I expect 'cannot GET /whatever/path'

But it always redirect to '/'

Why this happen?

And how can I turn off this redirection setting?

Comment: because you have not created routes to that paths yet.  See [Routing in react](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is standard with React apps to have this URL mapping you could change it using the URL mapping in backend say with DjangoRestFramework that is Async and for frontend web apps, and link it too the app but you're best leaving it as Facebook who made react do this:
[image]

So this is less of a problem but more of can you be arsed changing it, if you know django or a backend web framework this shouldn't be an issue it is as easy as changing a string in any language you use for the backend and other methods of backend are able to do this aswell not just frameworks.

JUST A LOCAL SEVER ANYWAY, TILL INTEGRATE A BACKEND.